# PDFCreator and COM

Tags: c++, pdf, com, pdf-generation

I'm trying to talk to PDFCreator from C++. There seems to be one example of this on various sites with slightly different versions. But something in the example worries me (maybe because I'm not a COM expert)...

```
  PDFCreator::_clsPDFCreatorOptionsPtr opt = pdfObject->GetcOptions();
  opt->UseAutosave = 1;
  opt->UseAutosaveDirectory = 1;
  opt->AutosaveDirectory = "c:\\temp\\";
  opt->AutosaveFormat = 0; // for PDF
  opt->AutosaveFilename = "gigi13";
  pdfObject->PutRefcOptions(opt);
```

So I get a pointer to the PDFCreator options, set them to what I want, then use `PutRefcOptions` to set the options inside PDFCreator.

So my stupid question is, if I've got a pointer to the options, aren't I just setting them directly when I, for example, `opt->AutoSave = 1` ?

Or does the `PDFCreator::_clsPDFCreatorOptionsPtr` hold a copy of the options? Maybe it is because `PDFCreator::_clsPDFCreatorOptionsPtr` is a smart pointer and so holds a copy of the options?

Comment: Not sure I understand where your confusion lies. A pointer *points to* an object. You're setting the values in the object itself, the pointer doesn't do anything except let you access the object.

Comment: Now I think the object exists on the stack, it is not "pointing inside" the PDFCreator. Hence I get a copy of the Options, change them, and put them "back into PDFCreator".

Comment: OK, I see the confusion now. We're talking about *two* different objects, the original pointed to by `pdfObject` and another one pointed to by `opt` that is a copy of the options. There's no reason to believe these are the same object, since the modifications you make need to be saved.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell (now!). opt is a smart pointer which creates a copy of the contents of the pdfObiect

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell (now!). opt is a smart pointer which creates a copy of the contents of the pdfObiect.

So I modify that copy and then send it back to pdfCreator. Makes sense.

Comment: It's not necessarily a copy of the entire object, just the options portion.

Comment: Yes, I was clumsy in the explanation. A copy of the whole options object is what I meant to say...